# Applying textures on cube geometry using THREE.js

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a simple THREE.js app that renders a cube and applies textures on each of the faces like so:

```
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5, 8, 1, 4, 4, 1);

var materials = [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('front.jpg') }),
//.....Front, back, left, etc...                              
]; 

...

var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

However, all I see is a black cube, i.e. the images dont appear ont the cube's faces.

Also, my code works fine in release 50 of the THREE.js library, so it seems like a change is a newer release has caused my code to break, and I cant seem to find any relavent documentation around it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Alright, can you try using simple colours instead of textures to see if it's a texture-related issue?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work as of release 97

```js
// creates cubes geometry in front of camera (assuming your camera position and rotation has not changed)
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1, -2, 0, 0);

// creates a texture loader for the cube
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader();

// defines variables to make things easier
var counter, textures = [], materials = [];

// iterate through all 6 sides of the cube
for(counter = 0; counter < 6; counter ++) {

  // loads and stores a texture (you might run into some problems with loading images directly from a source because of security protocols, so copying the image data is a for sure way to get the image to load)
  textures[counter] = texture.load('data:image/restOfImageAddress');

  // creates material from previously stored texture
  materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textures[counter]}));
}

// creates the cube by mixing the geometry and materials
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
```